# What does " will be made or broken" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, idioms, passive-voice

I'm trying to translate a [new smart phone review](http://blog.gsmarena.com/samsung-galaxy-j1-hands/). But I don't know what does "will be made or broken by its pricing" mean in the following context?

> The Samsung Galaxy J1 is a decent entry-level device that, just like
>   all of its peers, **will be made or broken by its pricing**. However if
>   you want to get it, you might want to look around for the quad-core
>   variant of it (given that rumors materialize and it actually does come
>   out) as it should provide a speed boost over the dual-core one. It is
>   available in either Black and Blue as well as White as in the case of
>   uor unit.

*[Review source](http://blog.gsmarena.com/samsung-galaxy-j1-hands/)*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The Samsung Galaxy J1 is a decent entry-level device that, just like all of its peers, **will be made or broken** by its pricing.

It's a reference to the idiom "[make-or-break](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/make-or-break)". The meaning is: the pricing of the new model will be the crucial factor that will either make it a hit or lead to its failure on the market.

It's an entry level device, hence probably cheap. A low price might attract buyers, but a low price is often associated with a lack of features. This could discourage those who prefer buying more expensive and feature-packed products.

If a company makes a device that is poor in features but fails to make the price low enough, consumers will consider the deal a rip-off and won't buy the item. This is especially important because those who buy entry-level phones are more sensitive to pricing than those who buy expensive phones. You've got to make your pricing just right.

The "make-or-break" idiom is often used in the media:

> Careers **are made or broken** by the way political leaders handle the kind of crises over which they ultimately have no control. (Boston Herald)
>
> Unions could **make or break** Hollande reforms. (Reuters)
>
> In his view there are two things that **make or break** a film — casting and editing — and he takes time with both. (Economic Times)

It's used in the passive voice, although not very often:

> Manchester United's season **will be made or broken** by the performance of newly appointed manager, Louis Van Gaal. (The Telegraph)
>
> "In the future, superpowers **will be made or broken** based on the strength of their cryptanalytic programs," says one document. (Inquirer)

Comment: I am curious to know the original senses of "make" and "break" in this idiom. My initial thought would be that it has to do with their promotion and demotion senses; that is, the Admiralty could "make" a Captain through promotion from a lower rank, but could also "break" one. But these sorts of idioms often have odd origins.